# how to get external ip address of agent in puppet template

Tags: puppet, erb

In puppet, the core fact [`ipaddress`](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/latest/core_facts.html#ipaddress) surely provides me with the agents private ipaddress.

Is there also a shortcut to retrieve the external ip address in an erb-template?

I guess I may have to write a small function for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ipaddress` fact just "does an `ifconfig` and returns the first non 127.0.0.0/8 subnetted IP it finds".  The code is [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/2.x/lib/facter/ipaddress.rb).  There are also facts available for the specific interfaces (`ipaddress_eth0` etc).  You may need to write a custom fact as you say, and it's very easy to do so.  (Documentation [here](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.1/custom_facts.html)).

All facts are available inside an ERB template as:

```
<%= @ipaddress %>
```

etc.